# Flash Lite 4 and Flex/Spark

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flashlite

I know the adobe docs doesn't say that flex and spark components are support in Flash Lite 4, but is that just because they are too heavy?

It seems to me that most of the spark components should run in Flash Lite 4.

At my company I'm in a weird situation.  We have beefy computers running Flash Lite 4, so performance is much better than mobile devices.

Flash Lite 4 supports a lot of Flash Player 10 features, so I'm thinking this would work.  Does anyone have a good reason why it would or wouldn't work?

Comment: I assume performance will be a major consideration.  Improvements are being made to Flex, Flash, and mobile device specs; but I expect Flash Lite to go away as opposed to Flex support being added.  Conceptually, it should work.  But, if you're targeting desktop why bother w/ Flash Lite?

Comment: There's a licensing issue with our machines.  They aren't connected to the internet so flash/air cant be updated.  We have to pay a special per machine license for flashlite.  This is all regulatory stuff so we can't change it.

Comment: Weird; In such a situation; I would probably recommend against using Flex in your development.

Answer (score 0):

Why would anyone ever want to use Flash Lite?  It's hasn't been updated in like 5-6 years and was only create for 'feature phones', not today's smart phones.

And no, Flex won't work on Flash Lite because it only supports AS2, and Flex uses AS3.  It's a whole different engine altogether.

As for you 'no internet' problem.  You can [package the latest version of Air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps.html) with your application, so that internet isn't needed at all, plus you'll have better control over the environment (Air version).

Comment: Flash Lite 4 supports AS3.  Trust us, no one here wants to use Flash Lite.

Comment: Flash Lite 4 supports AS3.  Trust us, no one here wants to use Flash Lite.  Right now they are using AS2 with Flash Lite 4 and they have tons of problems.

I think our licensing issue was decided before AIR came out.  I actually have an interview with the Flash team at my company today.  I'll have to bring up using Air, native extensions, stage 3D and packaging Air with the installer.

Comment: Supports as3 huh? didn't know that.  I would of thought Adobe wouldn't even bother updating Flash Lite.

Comment: Except you want to write an app for an app for a Samsung TV - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35XAm-IoOGA